# How can I vertically center a div element for all browsers using CSS?

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment, centering

I want to center a `div` vertically with CSS. I don't want tables or JavaScript, but only pure CSS. I found some solutions, but all of them are missing Internet Explorer 6 support.

```
<body>
    <div>Div to be aligned vertically</div>
</body>
```

How can I center a `div` vertically in all major browsers, including Internet Explorer 6?

Comment: In case people don't care about older browser support: http://davidwalsh.name/css-vertical-center

Comment: Here is lots of ways to do it https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 1556, accepted):

Below is the best all-around solution I could build to vertically and horizontally center a fixed-width, **flexible height** content box. It was tested and worked for recent versions of Firefox, Opera, Chrome, and Safari.

```css
.outer {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.inner {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 400px;
  /* Whatever width you want */
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      <h1>The Content</h1>
      <p>Once upon a midnight dreary...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[View A Working Example With Dynamic Content](http://emergentweb.com/test/valign.html)

I built in some dynamic content to test the flexibility and would love to know if anyone sees any problems with it. It should work well for centered overlays also -- lightbox, pop-up, etc.

Answer (score 367):

The simplest way would be the following **three lines** of CSS:

**1) position: relative;**

**2) top: 50%;**

**3) transform: translateY(-50%);**

Following is an **example**:

```css
div.outer-div {
  height: 170px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

div.middle-div {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class='outer-div'>
  <div class='middle-div'>
    Test text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: note: doesn't work correct if the height of the outer div is set with "min-height: 170px"

Comment: Interferes with z-index

Comment: doesn't work when `height` of outer `div` is `100%`. Then only works with `position: absolute;`.

Comment: I had found this solution elsewhere first, but extra kudos to this particular answer for mentioning the `-webkit-transform` variant in particular, which I needed to make this method work in phantomjs... ended hours of struggling so thank you!

Comment: This is the best answer. This is incredibly simple, messes with the least amount of existing work and functions on everything as far back as IE9 which nobody even uses anymore. Lets get this guy some more upvotes!

Comment: why do we need `translateY(-50%);` even though `top: 50%` itself already meaning center of the container? I know we need it, but why?

Comment: Why not just vertical margin auto?

Answer (score 311):

One more I can't see on the list:

```
.Center-Container {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}

.Absolute-Center {
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  overflow: auto;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;
  border: solid black;
}
```

- Cross-browser (including Internet Explorer 8 - Internet Explorer 10 without hacks!)
- Responsive with percentages and min-/max-
- Centered regardless of padding (without box-sizing!)
- `height` must be declared (see [Variable Height](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/#Height))
- Recommended setting `overflow: auto` to prevent content spillover (see Overflow)

<sub>Source: [Absolute Horizontal And Vertical Centering In CSS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css)</sub>

Answer (score 238):

Now the [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout) solution is a very easy way for modern browsers, so I recommend this for you:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>Div to be aligned vertically</div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you've got a `navbar`, you can tweak the height using `height: calc(100% - 55px)` or whatever the height of your `navbar` is.

Comment: i also had to remove margins/padding from body

Comment: Works well with `float`. Thanks.

Comment: Please note that this will potentially behave weird on "newer older" mobile safari browsers. The recommended use instead of height is flex-basis on the .container class

Comment: @NineMagics How does one do that?

Comment: To get rid of the vertical scrollbar, I had to also include `body { margin: 0; }`, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12989931/body-height-100-displaying-vertical-scrollbar).

Comment: How to center a div without container ? Let's say it's direct child of body element.

Answer (score 145):

Actually, you need two div's for vertical centering. The div containing the content must have a width and height.

```css
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  margin-top: -200px;
  /* Half of #content height */
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#content {
  width: 624px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  height: 395px;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="content">
    <h1>Centered div</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is [the result](http://jsfiddle.net/ssPDD/).

Comment: it's an old trick... top 50% and the top margin negative half the height for the inner div

Comment: it's assuming you have a fixed height for div. don't work when div can change height.

Answer (score 85):

Edit 2020: only use this if you need to support old browsers like [Internet Explorer 8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_8) (which you should refuse to do ). If not, use [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout).

---

This is the simplest method I found and I use it all the time
([jsFiddle demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/Nhs6j/)).

Thank Chris Coyier from CSS Tricks for [this article](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/).

```css
html, body{
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
.v-wrap{
    height: 100%;
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: center;
}
.v-wrap:before{
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 0;
    /* adjust for white space between pseudo element and next sibling */
    margin-right: -.25em;
    /* stretch line height */
    height: 100%;
}
.v-box{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="v-wrap">
    <article class="v-box">
        <p>This is how I've been doing it for some time</p>
    </article>
</div>
```

Support starts with Internet Explorer 8.

Comment: Refusing support for old browsers, the solution for me was not flexbox but grid system. It was a bit annoying for me center content in a container that, when it becames too small in height, needed to show scrollbar, and the centered content was loosing out the scroll area with all other methods. In the container i just use: 

{ display: grid; align-items: center; }

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 80):

After a lot of research I finally found the ultimate solution. It works even for floated elements. [View Source](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css)

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%); /* or try 50% */
}
```

Comment: This does works really well, provided you remember that the container element must have an implicit or explicit height; https://jsfiddle.net/14kt53un/

A minor gotcha to those who are relatively new to CSS.

Comment: Out of all the answers, this is the most simplest! I hope others see your answer too! Thank you! By the way, `50%` worked for me (not `-50%`)

Comment: That was incredible. After hours of searching, this one worked for me. I had to use translateY(50%) I am sure why, but it worked. In my case, the parent was created by AEM Forms Engine, and I can only control certain child elements.

Answer (score 68):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>This is centered vertically</div>
```

Comment: Note  `justify-content: center` will center items horizontally as well

Answer (score 39):

To center the div on a page, [check the fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/xKH7w/).

```css
#vh {
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
}
.box{
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="vh" class="box">Div to be aligned vertically</div>
```

Another option is to use flex box, [check the fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/abbasmhd/56mc4e2u/).

```css
.vh {
    background-color: #ddd;
    height: 400px;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
.vh > div {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="vh">
    <div>Div to be aligned vertically</div>
</div>
```

Another option is to use a CSS 3 transform:

```css
#vh {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    /*transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);*/
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.box{
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 25px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="vh" class="box">Div to be aligned vertically</div>
```

Comment: @ArmelLarcier That's incorrect. Relative units are percentages `%`, `em`s and `rem`s. Absolute or fixed values are pixels or points. What you're referring to is "it only works with a declared height". Howevever, although this method described by Moes does require a height, when you declare it in relative units, percentage is the best, no matter how much content is inside the centered DIV that DIV will expand vertically to fit its content. That's the beauty of this method. The other good thing is that this method works in IE8/9/10 in case someone still needs to support those browsers.

Comment: @ricardozea I don't mean to play stubborn but saying the centered div will expand vertically while remaining vertically centered is wrong. Try it. I know when I say the height must be "fixed", that it's not the right word. It is indeed relative, to its parent. Anyway I think Chris Coyer's method makes more sense, see my answer stackoverflow.com/a/21919578/1491212 It's compatible with IE8 AND does work on an element with no specified dimensions.

Comment: @ArmelLarcier It's all good. Is not wrong brother. Try it: http://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/gEiDt/ - Add paragraphs to the green box ;]. Granted, it uses Modernizr to accomplish the effect, but all in all it's doable. I saw your answer and the CSS-Tricks.com post as well, but that method doesn't make me happy, it uses extra markup and the CSS is too verbose. I think the best solution is either using flexbox or the `transform: translate(-50%, -50%);` technique. For IE8 I'd just leave it top/center aligned and move on.

Comment: @ricardozea Well the codepen you linked to uses the "display: table" method and extra markup so I'm not surprised. Anyways, +1 to your last sentence.

Answer (score 28):

The easiest solution is below:

```css
.outer-div{
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  border:1px solid #000;
}
.inner-div{
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-div">
  <div class="inner-div">
    Hey there!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Indeed the easiest one yet :) Although, I had to set the styles to a outer-div, instead of body.

Answer (score 25):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

**Using flex property of CSS.**

**Solution #1**

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height:200px;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.child {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

or by **using `display: flex;` and `margin: auto;`**

**Solution #2**

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height:200px;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
}

.child {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: yellow;
    margin:auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

**show text center**

Solution #3

```css
.parent {
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    background: yellow;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">Center</div>
```

**Using percentage(%) height and width.**

Solution #4

```css
.parent {
    position: absolute;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: blue;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content:center;
}

.child {
    width: 75px;
    height: 75px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 22):

Unfortunately — but not surprisingly — the solution is more complicated than one would wish it to be. Also unfortunately, you'll need to use additional divs around the div you want vertically centered.

For standards-compliant browsers like Mozilla, Opera, Safari, etc. you need to set the outer div to be displayed as a *table* and the inner div to be displayed as a *table-cell* — which can then be vertically centered. For Internet Explorer, you need to *position* the inner div *absolutely* within the outer div and then specify the *top* as *50%*. The following pages explain this technique well and provide some code samples too:

- [Vertical Centering in CSS](http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html)
- [Vertical Centering in CSS with Unknown Height (Internet Explorer 7 compatible)](http://web.archive.org/web/20101107022613/http://www.laboratoriocaffeina.it/design/2007/05/11/vertical-centering-in-css-with-unknown-height-ie7-compatible.html) (Archived article courtesy of the Wayback Machine)

There is also a technique to do the vertical centering using JavaScript. [Vertical alignment of content with JavaScript & CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/d/footers/footer_variation1.html) demonstrates it.

Answer (score 21):

If someone cares for Internet Explorer 10 (and later) only, use [Flexbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout):

```css
.parent {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    background: yellow;

    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;

    -webkit-justify-content: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
    justify-content: center;

    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -ms-flex-align: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.centered {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="centered"></div>
</div>
```

Flexbox support: http://caniuse.com/flexbox

Comment: Android < 4.4 doesn't support `align-items: center;` !

Comment: Actually, it does support align-items: center; 
http://caniuse.com/#search=align-items

Comment: @t.mikael.d You might want to take a closer look at that table. For Android < 4.4, it states "Only supports the old flexbox specification and does not support wrapping."

Answer (score 21):

A modern way to center an element vertically would be to use [`flexbox`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

You need a parent to decide the height and a child to center.

The example below will center a div to the center within your browser. What's important (in my example) is to set `height: 100%` to `body` and `html` and then `min-height: 100%` to your container.

```css
body, html {
  background: #F5F5F5;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#center_container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

#center {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id='center_container'>
  <div id='center'>I am center.</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 15):

## Centering only vertically

If you don't care about Internet Explorer 6 and 7, you can use a technique that involves two containers.

### The outer container:

- should have `display: table;`

### The inner container:

- should have `display: table-cell;`
- should have `vertical-align: middle;`

### The content box:

- should have `display: inline-block;`

You can add any content you want to the content box without caring about its width or height!

### **Demo:**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* This could be ANY width */
    height: 100%; /* This could be ANY height */
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
        Malcolm in the Middle
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr4eay5e/1/)!

---

## Centering horizontally and vertically

If you want to center both horizontally and vertically, you also need the following.

### The inner container:

- should have `text-align: center;`

### The content box:

- should re-adjust the horizontal text-alignment to for example `text-align: left;` or `text-align: right;`, unless you want text to be centered

### **Demo:**

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

.outer-container {
    position: absolute;
    display: table;
    width: 100%; /* This could be ANY width */
    height: 100%; /* This could be ANY height */
    background: #ccc;
}

.inner-container {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.centered-content {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: left;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer-container">
   <div class="inner-container">
     <div class="centered-content">
         Malcolm in the Middle
     </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lr4eay5e/4/)!

Answer (score 15):

```css
.center {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* (x, y)  => position */
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */    
}

.vertical {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  //left: 0;
  transform: translate(0, -50%); /* (x, y) => position */
}

.horizontal {
  position: absolute;
  //top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 0); /* (x, y)  => position */
}

div {
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: grey; 
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="vertical">Vertically left</div>
  <div class="horizontal">Horizontal top</div>
  <div class="center">Vertically Horizontal</div>  
</body>
```

Related: [Center a Image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16702881/center-image-vertical-and-horizontal/46375063#46375063)

Answer (score 12):

It can be done in two ways

```
body{
left: 50%; 
top:50%; 
transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
height: 100%; 
width: 100%; 
}
```

OR

Using flex

```
body {
    height:100%
    width:100%
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

`align-items:center;` makes the content vertically center

`justify-content: center;`makes the content horizontally center

Answer (score 10):

This is always where I go when I have to come back to [this issue](http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html).

For those who don't want to make the jump:

1. Specify the parent container as `position:relative` or `position:absolute`.
2. Specify a fixed height on the child container.
3. Set `position:absolute` and `top:50%` on the child container to move the top down to the middle of the parent.
4. Set margin-top:-yy where yy is half the height of the child container to offset the item up.

An example of this in code:

```
<style type="text/css">
    #myoutercontainer {position:relative}
    #myinnercontainer {position:absolute; top:50%; height:10em; margin-top:-5em}
</style>
...
<div id="myoutercontainer">
    <div id="myinnercontainer">
        <p>Hey look! I'm vertically centered!</p>
        <p>How sweet is this?!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `5em` isn't always half the height of the child container.

Answer (score 9):

I just wrote this CSS and to know more, please go through: [This article with vertical align anything with just 3 lines of CSS](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

```
.element {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: perspective(1px) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: CSS transforms can cause distortions in text and borders (when the math results in fractional pixels).

Answer (score 8):

### CSS Grid

```css
body, html { margin: 0; }

body {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>Div to be aligned vertically</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

For newcomers, please try:

```
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Comment: Please add a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) showing how this CSS code **vertically** aligns a `div`.

Comment: this works too

`<div style="display:flex"><div style="margin:auto">Inner</div></div>`

Comment: I came across with this wonderful explanation of align items and justify content.

Must Read :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42613359/how-does-flex-wrap-work-with-align-self-align-items-and-align-content

Answer (score 7):

The three lines of code using `transform` works practically on modern browsers and Internet Explorer:

```
.element{
     position: relative;
     top: 50%;
     transform: translateY(-50%);
     -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
     -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
     -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I am adding this answer since I found some incompleteness in the previous version of this answer (and Stack Overflow won't allow me to simply comment).

1. 'position' relative messes up the styling if the current div is in the body and has no container div. However 'fixed' seems to work, but it obviously fixes the content in the center of the viewport
   [image: position: relative]
2. Also I used this styling for centering some overlay divs and found that in Mozilla all elements inside this transformed div had lost their bottom borders. Possibly a rendering issue. But adding just the minimal padding to some of them rendered it correctly. Chrome and Internet Explorer (surprisingly) rendered the boxes without any need for padding
   [image: mozilla without inner paddings]
   [image: mozilla with paddings]

Answer (score 7):

```
.center{
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}
```

Comment: adding `height: 100%;` centers it also vertically.

Comment: Addendum - 'place-content:' does the trick, both directions. :) Can't believe I have to scroll this far and it has so few votes.

Answer (score 4):

The answer from Billbad only works with a fixed width of the `.inner` div.
This solution works for a dynamic width by adding the attribute `text-align: center` to the `.outer` div.

```css
.outer {
  position: absolute;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
.middle {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.inner {
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="outer">
  <div class="middle">
    <div class="inner">
      Content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting! I'm using an almost identical technique! -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers/34914203#34914203

Answer (score 4):

Just do it: Add the class at your `div`:

```
.modal {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 240px;
}
```

And read [this article](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/08/09/absolute-horizontal-vertical-centering-css/) for an explanation. Note: `Height` is necessary.

Answer (score 3):

I did it with this (change width, height, margin-top and margin-left accordingly):

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 960px;
    height: 590px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -295px;
    margin-left: -480px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"> -- Content -- </div>
```

Comment: Thats only good if you know the width/height of the DIV your trying to center. This isn't what the question is asking

Answer (score 3):

Not answering for browser compatibility but to also mention the new Grid and the not so new Flexbox feature.

**Grid**

From: [Mozilla - Grid Documentation - Align Div Vertically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Box_Alignment_in_CSS_Grid_Layout#Center_an_item_in_the_area)

Browser Support: [Grid Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid)

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  grid-template-areas: 
    ". a a ."
    ". a a .";
}
.item1 {
  grid-area: a;
  align-self: center;
  justify-self: center;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
 <div class="item1">Item 1</div>
</div>
```

**Flexbox**

Browser Support: [Flexbox Browser Support](https://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

CSS:

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -moz-box;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think a solid solution for all browsers without using Flexbox - "align-items: center;" is a combination of display: table and vertical-align: middle;.

#### CSS

```
.vertically-center
{
    display: table;

    width: 100%;  /* Optional */
    height: 100%; /* Optional */
}

.vertically-center > div
{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

#### HTML

```
<div class="vertically-center">
    <div>
        <div style="border: 1px solid black;">some text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

‣Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6m640rpp/

Answer (score 1):

Especially for parent divs with relative (unknown) height, the [centering in the unknown](http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown/) solution works great for me. There are some really nice code examples in the article.

It was tested in Chrome, Firefox, Opera, and Internet Explorer.

```css
/* This parent can be any width and height */
.block {
  text-align: center;
}

/* The ghost, nudged to maintain perfect centering */
.block:before {
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: -0.25em; /* Adjusts for spacing */
}

/* The element to be centered, can
   also be of any width and height */ 
.centered {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 400px; height: 200px;">
   <div class="block" style="height: 90%; width: 100%">
  <div class="centered">
  <h1>Some text</h1>
  <p>Any other text..."</p>
  </div> 
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The contents can be easily centered by using Flexbox. The following code shows the CSS for the container inside which the contents needs to be centered:

```css
.absolute-center {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    align-items: center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a trick I found out recently: You need to use `top 50%`, and then you do a `translateY(-50%)`.

```css
.outer-div {
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.centered-div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class='outer-div'>
  <div class='centered-div'>
    Test text
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Now we can use the `align-content` on block layouts without the need of flexbox or CSS grid.

You can test the below using the latest version of chrome.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  align-content: center; /* vertical centering*/
}

/* the below is for horizontal centering (irrelevant to the question) */
div {
  width: fit-content;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Div to be aligned vertically</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I find this one most useful... It gives the most accurate 'H' layout and is very simple to understand.

The benefit of this markup is that you define your content size in a single place -> "PageContent".

The Colors of the page background and its horizontal margins are defined in their corresponding divs.

```html
<div id="PageLayoutConfiguration"
     style="display: table;
     position:absolute; top: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px;
     width: 100%; height: 100%;">

    <div id="PageBackground"
         style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;
         background-color: purple;">

        <div id="PageHorizontalMargins"
             style="width: 100%;
             background-color: seashell;">

            <div id="PageContent"
                 style="width: 1200px; height: 620px; margin: 0 auto;
                 background-color: grey;">

                 My content goes here...

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here with CSS separated:

```html
<div id="PageLayoutConfiguration">
     <div id="PageBackground">
          <div id="PageHorizontalMargins">
               <div id="PageContent">
                     my content goes here...
               </div>
          </div>
     </div>
</div>
```

```css
#PageLayoutConfiguration{
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   position: absolute;
   top: 0px;
   right: 0px;
   bottom: 0px;
   left: 0px;
}

#PageBackground{
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
   background-color: purple;
}

#PageHorizontalMargins{
   width: 100%;
   background-color: seashell;
}
#PageContent{
   width: 1200px;
   height: 620px;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this. It works in Internet Explorer 8 and later:

`height:268px` - for `display:table` acts like min-height.

CSS:

```
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
body {
  background: #cc9999;
}
p {
  background: #f0ad4e;
}
#all {
  margin: 200px auto;
}
.ff-valign-wrap {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
  height: 268px;
  background: #ff00ff;
}
.ff-valign {
  display: table-cell;
  height: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ffff00;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>

  <div id="all">
    <div class="ff-valign-wrap">
      <div class="ff-valign">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi autem doloribus earum expedita, ipsum laboriosam nostrum nulla officiis optio quam quis quod sunt tempora tenetur veritatis vero voluptatem voluptates?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi autem doloribus earum expedita, ipsum laboriosam nostrum nulla officiis optio quam quis quod sunt tempora tenetur veritatis vero voluptatem voluptates?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi autem doloribus earum expedita, ipsum laboriosam nostrum nulla officiis optio quam quis quod sunt tempora tenetur veritatis vero voluptatem voluptates?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi autem doloribus earum expedita, ipsum laboriosam nostrum nulla officiis optio quam quis quod sunt tempora tenetur veritatis vero voluptatem voluptates?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi autem doloribus earum expedita, ipsum laboriosam nostrum nulla officiis optio quam quis quod sunt tempora tenetur veritatis vero voluptatem voluptates?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi autem doloribus earum expedita, ipsum laboriosam nostrum nulla officiis optio quam quis quod sunt tempora tenetur veritatis vero voluptatem voluptates?</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet, animi autem doloribus earum expedita, ipsum laboriosam nostrum nulla officiis optio quam quis quod sunt tempora tenetur veritatis vero voluptatem voluptates?</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me for a block element (e.g., <div>). I used the colors to make the solution clearer.

**HTML:**

```
<main class="skin_orange">
    <p>As you can the the element/box is vertically centered</p>
    <div class="bigBox skin_blue">Blue Box</div>
</main>
```

**CSS:**

```
main {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

.skin_orange {
    outline: thin dotted red;
    background: orange;
}

.bigBox {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.skin_blue {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

[JSFiddle Code Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/efebirol/26zLrys3/)

Answer (score -1):

I just found another way which worked for me:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="vertical">
     <h1>Welcome</h1>
     <h2>Aligned Vertically</h2>
     <a href="#">Click ME</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.vertical{
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

[More information](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/)

Answer (score -1):

Vertical & Horizontal **CENTER**

HTML

```
<div id="dialog">Centered Dialog</div>
```

CSS

```
#dialog {
    position:fixed; top:50%; left:50%; z-index:99991;
    width:300px; height:60px;
    margin-top:-150px;  /* half of the width */
    margin-left:-30px; /* half of the height */}
```

Enjoy!

Answer (score -1):

By using the `transform` property we can do a vertically centered div easily.

```css
.main-div {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #999;
    font-size: 18px;
    height: 450px;
    max-width: 850px;
    padding: 15px;
}

.vertical-center {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #1FA67A;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 15px;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
    <div class="vertical-center">
        <span>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

[See here for full article](http://code.ciphertrick.com/2015/02/10/vertically-center-div-using-css3/)

Answer (score -1):

To vertical-align a box in web page, including Internet Explorer 6, you may use:

1. Conditional comments
2. The `haslayout` property
3. `display: table-value` for others (and now flex)

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h8z24s5v/embedded/result/)

```css
/* Internet Explorer 8 and others */
.main {
  width: 500px;
  margin: auto;
  border: solid;
}
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
body {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!-- [if lte IE 7]>
<style> /* Should be in the <head> */
    html, body , .ie {
        height: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }
    .ie , .main{
        display: inline; /* Used with zoom in case you take a block element instead an inline element */
        zoom: 1;
        vertical-align: middle;
        text-align: left;
        white-space: normal;
    }
</style>
<b class="ie"></b>
<!--[endif]-->
<div class="main">
  <p>Fill it up with your content </p>
  <p><a href="https://jsfiddle.net/h8z24s5v/embedded/result/">JsFiddle versie</a></p>
</div>
```

Actually, Internet Explorer 7 would bring some trouble here being the only which will strictly apply `height: 100%` on HTML/body elements.

---

**But, *this is past and today and who still minds old versions of Internet Explorer, `table/table-cell` is just fine, `display: flex` is promising, and `display: grid` will show up some day.***

---

Another nowdays example via flex

```css
html {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100vh;/* or height */
}

body {
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>Div to be aligned vertically</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

The best thing to do would be:

```
#vertalign{
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  top: calc(50vh - 150px); 
}
```

150 pixels because that's half of the div's height in this case.

Comment: I wouldn't call using fixed values "the best".

Answer (score -1):

Declare this Mixin:

```
@mixin vertical-align($position: relative) {
  position: $position;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Then include it in your element:

```
.element{
    @include vertical-align();
}
```

Comment: this is plain css? what about browser support?

Answer (score -1):

The following is working in my case and was tested in Firefox.

```
#element {
    display: block;
    transform: translateY(50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(50%);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(50%);
    -ms-transform: translateY(50%);
}
```

The div's height and parent's height are dynamic. I use it when there are other elements on the same parent which is higher than the target element, where both are positioned horizontally inline.

Comment: [This doesn't work.](https://jsfiddle.net/gktnjcha/)

Answer (score -1):

This is by far the easiest approach and works on non-blocking elements as well. The only downside is it's Flexbox, thus, older browsers will not support this.

```
<div class="sweet-overlay">
    <img class="centered" src="http://jimpunk.com/Loading/loading83.gif" />
</div>
```

Link to CodePen:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/LNOdRp

The important point here is, for vertical centering, we need to define a parent element (container) and the img must have a smaller height than the parent element.

Comment: link broken .. please add the relevant css directly to the answer

Answer (score -1):

This method doesn't use any transform. So it doesn't have a problem with the output becoming blurry.

```
position: absolute;
width: 100vw;
top: 25%;
bottom: 25%;
text-align: center;
```

Comment: [This doesn't center](https://jsfiddle.net/1b0mxvg9/)

Answer (score -1):

Since each time I need to center div vertically I google for it over and over again and this answer always comes first I'll leave this for future me (since none of the provided solutions fit my need well):

So if one is already using bootstrap this can be done as below:

```
<div style="min-height: 100vh;" class="align-items-center row">
    <div class="col" style="margin: auto; max-width: 750px;"> //optional style to center horizontally as well

    //content goes here

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I shared short version for who is want.

```css
.firstDivision {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.firstDivision .verticalCenter {
  text-align: center;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="firstDivision">
  <div class="verticalCenter">
    Text was centered for Vertical.
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

## Using Flexbox

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
height: 100%;
```

Comment: There is plenty of existing answers already proposing flexbox.

Answer (score -1):

Here I'm listing all the possible ways available to vertically align the div. I would prefer Flexbox because Flexbox simplifies this process by automatically adjusting margins and positioning of elements relative to each other.

```
<body class="body-container">
    <div class="content">Div to be aligned vertically</div>
</body>
```

1. **Using Flexbox:**

   ```
    .body-container {
     display: flex;
     align-items: center; // vertical alignment 
     justify-content: center; // horizontal alignment, if needed 
     height: 100%; // adjust as needed 
    }
   ```
2. **Using Grid:**

   ```
   .body-container {
    display: grid;
    place-items: center; 
    height: 100%;
   }
   ```

Note:  place-item shorthand property allows you to align items along both the block and inline directions at once (i.e. the align-items and justify-items properties) in a relevant layout system such as Grid or Flexbox.

3. **Using Table-cell:**

   ```
    .body-container {
     display: table-cell;
     vertical-align: middle;
     text-align: center; // horizontal alignment, if needed 
     height: 100%; // adjust as needed 
    }
   ```
4. **Using Positioning and Transform:**

   ```
   .body-container {
     position: relative;
     height: 100%;
    }

   .content {
     position: absolute;
     top: 50%;
     left: 50%;
     transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    }
   ```
5. **Using CSS Grid with auto margin:**

   ```
   .body-container {
    display: grid;
    height: 100%;
   }

   .content {
    margin: auto;
   }
   ```

Answer (score -3):

Here is a simple way, with almost no code:

CSS code:

```
.main{
    height: 100%;
}

.center{
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: 50%;
}
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="center">
        Hi, I am centered!
    </div>
</div>
```

Your text will be in the middle of the page!

Comment: [This doesn't work](https://jsfiddle.net/y38L2zfm/)

Answer (score -4):

This worked in my case (only tested in modern browsers):

```
.textthatneedstobecentered {
  margin: auto;
  top: 0; bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: [This doesn't work at all](https://jsfiddle.net/agnf5mhz/)