# vertical align asp panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, panel, vertical-alignment

I have a panel in asp page and I want to add image to this panel so that this image is located at the center of the panel:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Panel panel = new Panel();
    panel.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;  
    //here I want set verticalAlign for the panel

    Image image = new Image();
    image.imageURL = imageurl;
    panel.controls.add(image);
    this.form1.controls.add(panel);
}
```

I tried using CSS:

```
p.CssClass = "css1";
```

and css is:

```
<style type="text/css"> 
        .css1
        {
            vertical-align: middle;              
        }
</style>
```

but this didn't give result.

So, how to locate image in center of the panel (horizontally and vertically)?

Please, do not recommend

```
padding-top:20px;
```

this changes the height of the panel. I must keep dimensions of panel constantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A panel just renders as a div, so the answers to this question should be of use:

[Align vertically using CSS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412912/align-vertically-using-css-3)   (The second answer in particular, by @j-man86, has detail on two ways of solving the problem).

If you just want `vertical-align: middle;` to work, then the easiest way is to add `display: table-cell;` to the same css declaration, but that's not necessarily the best CSS solution to vertical alignment.