# How to vertically align div text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have 2 div floating side by side.

The div on the left is a part number, only one line. The div on the right is a product description and can have multiple lines.

How can I vertically align the left div text when the right div grows to 2 or more line.

Here is the code.

```
<td>
   <div class="prodNumber left partNumSizexSmall">
      <a href="link" style="color:blue;text-decoration:underline;"><b>PartNum</b></a>
   </div>
   <div class="prodDesc xsmallDesc left">
      ProductDescription1
   </div>
</td>
```

Here is the CSS

```
.left {
    float: left;
}
.prodNumber {

}

.prodDesc {
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}
.partNumSizexSmall {
    min-width: 50px;
}
.xsmallDesc {
    max-width: 550px;
}
```

Comment: See here:
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939914/vertically-align-text-in-a-div

Comment: I had this exact problem with multi-line text and I wanted a CSS solution that didn't require table-cell - there's an alternate solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994549/trouble-vertically-centering-text-in-another-div-with-relative-sizing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use table instead of div

```
         <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td class="prodNumber left partNumSizexSmall">
                        <a href="link" style="color: blue; text-decoration: underline;"><b>PartNum</b></a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="prodDesc xsmallDesc left">
                        ProductDescription1 ProductDescription1 ProductDescription1 ProductDescription1
                        ProductDescription1 ProductDescription1 ProductDescription1 ProductDescription1
                        Product Description1 Product Description1 Product Description1 Product Description1
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
```

Answer (score 0):

The div to have it's content centered needs the `display: table-cell`

```
.center_me {
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle; 
    display:table-cell;
}
```

The `display:table-cell` is what allows an element to have children vertically aligned, so it has to be on the parent to be able to have the children aligned vertically.

Here's a [working JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/zcU7M/25/).

Answer (score 0):

Use line-height.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var newheight = $(".prodDesc").height();
    var newheight2 = $(".prodNumber").height();
   if( newheight > newheight2 ){
        $(".prodNumber").css("line-height", newheight);
    }else if( newheight2 > newheight ){
         $(".prodDesc").css("line-height", newheight2);
    }
});
```

Should work, but I didnt test it. sorry.

Comment: Doesn't work for multi-line text which is exactly what the OP says he has.

Comment: Good point threw in an edit. I was only thinking about the right side before being multi-line. That should be better. If not, Ill let someone else answer it. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

the most proven solution is to apply main container as display:table; and the children as display:table-cell. Since as per ur requirement you want the both prodNumber & prodDesc to be dependent on each other hence please add one outside wrap which holds both these elements. See working file here: `url`http://jsfiddle.net/wZ3n3/

PS: append more texts.

Hope you got answer.

Answer (score -1):

Use somthing like this

```
<div align="center">
This is some text!
</div>
```

Comment: Align is a deprecated attribute http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/graphics.html#h-15.1.2

Comment: Not only does it not work, it's not even the correct outdated way to *vertically* center something. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/q2J9k/