# center text inside a div element

Tags: html, css

I have a simple piece of html:

```
  <div style="width:60%;color:#000;text-align:center;">
    This is a test
  </div>
```

I want to center the text that is inside the div, but it is not working. I have tried other solutions in similar stack overflow questions but to no avail. I have tried using the use text-align in a paragraph element, but that does not work also. How can I get it to center horizontally?

It is presently aligning left.

Comment: Take a look at this answer :-)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994549/trouble-vertically-centering-text-in-another-div-with-relative-sizing/16195362#16195362

Comment: Your code is working fine. http://jsfiddle.net/FdA4N/

Comment: text is center, your div is not center

Comment: Your code seems to be fine, can you share your complete code.

Comment: To easily debug issues like this, put a border on your container so you can see the position of it like @SureshPonnukalai did

Comment: Thanks guys. ABFORCE, I tried doing it inside a p block which did not work as well.

Comment: Once again, thanks, this is all great advice. I am learning. :)

Comment: can you create a http://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Here are two simple methods to center elements within a div, vertically, horizontally or both (pure CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/a/31977476/3597276

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working on my machine.

The way you have it written, the string will center itself within 60% of the div's available space. This will have an effect of looking slightly off-center, but technically centered within your div.

If you want it dead center in the middle of your page, change the width to 100%.

Answer (score -2):

Try using:

```
 <center>
    your text here
 </center>
```

inside your div

Comment: `center` tag is deprecated

Comment: yes i know. but normally "align: center" work and it's only solution

Comment: @user3648426 your code work on my computer so verify if div width is 80% on your screen

Answer (score -2):

I just want to add that using `<section>` instead of  also works for the specific purpose I need.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.

Comment: @EugenePodskal This is not a "thank you" type answer. Check the edit.

Comment: OK, as I said, for my purposes, this got the job done. One thing about stack overflow is that some people become Nazis here.