# CSS Center text (Horizontal and Vertical) over another element inside a DIV block

Tags: html, css, svg

I am trying to center text over an SVG element inside a DIV. I have put together a simple model of my target in this [JsFiddle Example, Here](https://jsfiddle.net/s4gx5m12/1/).

CSS:

```
body {
  background-color: #efefef;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 20px 0 0 20px;
}

.mainScr {
  max-width: 1500px;
  margin: 1px;

}

.mainInfo {
  background-color: #D4FCD5;
  min-width: 495px;
  max-width: 1470px; 
  min-height: 100px;
  border: 1px double green;
}

.screenParts {
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 49%;
  max-width: 730px;
  min-width: 495px;
  min-height: 450px;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #F7E7C4;
  margin: 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.displayText {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  line-height: 0.75em;
  margin: 0.5em;
}    

.graphicsPanel {
  width: 100%;
  height: 66%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
  display: table;
  text-align: center;
}

.displayValues {
  /*this combination works better along x, but not good along y*/
  position:relative;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;                 
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(+50%);
  /*transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(+600%);*/



  /* this combination keeps target in the middle of the screen!
  position:absolute;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);              
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;*/   
}
```

HTML:

```
    </div>
    <div class="mainScr">
      <div id="visual" class="screenParts">
        <div class="graphicsPanel">
          <div class="displayValues">
        <p id="titleLabel" class="displayText">ParamName</p>
        <p id="valuLabel" class="displayText">Value</p>
        <p id="timerLabel" class="displayText">Description</p>
          </div>
<!--SVG Circle goes here, I removed it to prevent screen cluttering here, but it is included in the original JsFiddle Link-->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The goal is to centralize all three lines of text (vertically and horizontally) in the middle of that circle. (In the main work, the circle is a more complex HMI that displays some information like a clock or a compass with hands and a JS code controls it.) I also need my parent div (*graphicsPanel*) to only occupy half-ish of the screen as specified in the css code.

So far I have tried all options [in the answers to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5703552/css-center-text-horizontal-and-vertical-inside-a-div-block).

Some of the reasons that they don't quite work is:

- I have more than one line of text to display
- The height of the text lines are not fixed (in the real work, each
  text line has its own specific height)
- the height/size of the parent div (*graphicsPanel*) is not fixed.
- I'd like the text to be floating on the center of the circle, not
  before it or above it or, ....

I really like a html/css solution. My plan B and C options will be:

- **Plan B:** Write a JS code that moves the text dynamically on screen
  size changed event.
- **Plan C:** Write the text in the SVG and have the same JS that moves the
  clock hands, update the text.

***HOWEVER***, My goal is to have he least amount of SVG (and JS workarounds) and replace them with clean/nice html and css if possible at all.

Thanks everyone in advance.

---

***Final Answer:*** (So Far, other suggestions are still welcome!)

As Rob Barber and Roberto S. suggested (and my self after a couple of try and errors), adding the position: relative to the parent div (*graphicsPanel*) and making the text div (*.displayValues*), positioned absolutely (with respect to its parent) will get me the desired results.

```
.graphicsPanel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 66%;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  background: lightblue;
}

.displayValues {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%; 
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);              
}
```

Comment: Actually I came across this question and answer and they seem to be working fine, I will look into them this afternoon, Please dont down vote form now. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994549/trouble-vertically-centering-text-in-another-div-with-relative-sizing/16195362#16195362

Comment: Even in above example, when I added the SVG circle, the text-align:center attribute of ".tx" paragraph stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position on .displayValues will position against the first ancestor node that has a non-static position. If none are defined, it will go up to the window and position against the viewport instead of the SVG you're trying to center over. Adding a position: relative to .graphicsPanel, will position .displayValues against it instead of the window.

Comment: Thanks, Just tried it but unfortunately it did not work.

Comment: I was going to suggest the same, too. That's what I did. https://jsfiddle.net/yy4at7v4/

Comment: Thanks! It actually looks to be working with a little bit of tweaking!

Comment: @RobertoS., Thanks! apparently we reached the same result.