# text centering on CSS with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I'm learning `flex box` and can not get my text to center align.

I am aware I can center align vertically using `padding`, but I want it to be more of an automatic centering and not edit each item every time.

Although [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13994549/trouble-vertically-centering-text-in-another-div-with-relative-sizing/16195362#16195362) did help, it was not what I was looking for.

I need to get my `.item` to center horizontally and vertically with the minimum amount of code.

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/benbeck1990/pen/JKJJPm/)

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.item {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px;
  width: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <h2> Display: flex </h2>
  <div class="example-content">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="item">If you wanna</div>
      <div class="item">Then you gotta</div>
      <div class="item">Go findz it</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To center *.item* children within *.parent*, use the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title></title>
        <style>
            .parent {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                height: 200px;
            }
            .item {
                align-content: center;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="example">
            <h2> Display: flex </h2>
            <div class="example-content">
                <div class="parent">
                    <div class="item">If you wanna</div>
                    <div class="item">Then you gotta</div>
                    <div class="item">Go findz it</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to add [`align-items:center`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/align-items) and a new `display:flex` to the child

```css
body {
  margin: 0
}
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: black solid;
  color: white
}
.item {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  background: lightgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <h2> Display: flex </h2>
  <div class="example-content">
    <div class="parent">
      <div class="item">If you wanna</div>
      <div class="item">Then you gotta</div>
      <div class="item">Go findz it</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```