# How do I center text inside of the border?

Tags: html, css

[How would I go about moving the text so that it's in the center](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqONf.png)

This is what I have in my stylesheet

```html
.box {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use flex or other funky styling - but the simplest way is to use line height which is set to the same as the height of the container.

```css
.box {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid white;
  font-family: Arial;
  height: 30px;
  line-height: 30px
}
```

```html
<div class="box">This is centered text</div>
```

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16195362/898364

Comment: with you actual Rep, you should know that this question is very very very common and we already have plenty of duplicate