# Center div in parent with only min-height, and child may without height & with relative position

Tags: css, centering

so I have a div which is min-height 100%; (100% of the screen or more). The child holds the content and needs to be centered vertically, but it might extend the parent to more than 100% of its size. This child is variable in height.

So is there a way with only css(3) to do this?

Comment: Table display, possibly?

Comment: You talking about something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/tL7t9/

Comment: No, I want to manage this: http://vea.re without js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `display: table;` and `display: table-cell;` properties.

The outer DIV will need to have `display: table;` and the inner DIV `display: table-cell;` along with `vertical-align: middle;`.  Now you will be mimicing the default display of a `td`.

**CSS**

```css
.parent {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.child {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="parent">
     <div class="child">child</div>
</div>
```

This question has been asked often.  A simple search here on SO or Google will get you plenting of results.

- [How to vertically center divs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743989/vertically-aligning-divs)
- [Align vertically using CSS 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5412912/align-vertically-using-css-3)

Comment: Yeah, I did a search and the results did not work, yours did though, because the other people did not specify the display: table; on the parent. Thanks.

Comment: I have noticed that in the past.  People will suggest `display: table-cell;` but not note that the parent element should have `display: table;` also.  I will include this in my answer for future users.