# Vertical alignment in div with unknown parent height

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment

Yes, the saga continues: Presently the only reliable way of getting vertical alignment within nested DIVs is supposedly to [use a `display-table;` property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17658870/center-div-in-parent-with-only-min-height-and-child-may-without-height-with-r).

Here's a simple fiddle showing it not working: http://jsfiddle.net/aDbFb/1/

or have I misunderstood the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `float` property when you are using `display:table` and `table-cell`. So just remove them from your inline style and then everything will work as expected.

[Js Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aDbFb/2/)