# Vertically centering a div in body?

Tags: html, css, centering

I have tried to center this vertically in `body` (not horizontally). Also, I do not want to specify heights or anything like that. I tried adding a wrapper with a 100% height and other things, but got nowhere. Can you please help me fix this?

[jsFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Hunter4854/23NUC/)

```
 <form name="signup" class="signup" action="signup.php" style="border: 1px solid #000; ">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/><br>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/><br>
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/><br>
     <button type="submit">Next</button>
 </form>​
```

Comment: when it comes to heighs the fast answer is always "you can't". Html pages are intended to be vertically scrolled and heights should be free to change according to the content. So there's no proper way to center your div vertically with css and html. allthought there can be some javascript/jQuery workarounds if you're keen to learn that.

Comment: There is no overflow on the website..so, why is there not a way to vertically align a div?

Comment: What about wrapping it in a table and using the valign attribute? '<td valign="top|middle|bottom|baseline">' also there is more information here that you might find useful. http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div

Comment: @Rhys i would like to avoid the use of tables if possible. Or, could you give me a jsfiddle example to look at? Thanks!

Comment: I have to head to work, but there are some examples on this page that should help. http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

Comment: here's a jQuery fiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/23NUC/3/

Comment: Wouldn't it be wonderful if the people over at W3 decided to add a `vertical-positioning` CSS property with `initial`, `inherit`, `top`, `bottom`, and `middle`?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

See [this edited version of your jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/kj76C/).

Basically, just wrap your content in `<div class = "main"><div class = "wrapper"></div></div>`, and add the following CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
.main {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}
.wrapper {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: why do i have to have a main, wrapper, then my object...also, my body has a 100% height background image, and the height attribute makes it overflow.

Comment: @EliteGamer The overflow is coming from `padding` or `margins`, remove them by setting `margin: 0; padding: 0;` or add a [CSS Normalize](http://fiddle.jshell.net/css/normalize.css) to your page to avoid future issues. The two wrappers are necessary for centering; I'm afraid that's the only way to go if you don't want to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 16):

If you have flexbox available, you can do it without using `display: table;`

Code example:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="content">
        This div will be centered
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Ta-da! Vertically and horizontally centered content div. JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/z0g0htm5/.

Taken mostly from https://philipwalton.github.io/solved-by-flexbox/demos/vertical-centering/ and https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: I think this is the best answer. I wish I could upvote more than once.

Answer (score 11):

Update: [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/css-vertically-centering-a-div-in-body-zymim?file=/index.html)

```css
form {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */     
}
```

```html
<form name="signup" class="signup" action="signup.php" style="border: 1px solid #000; ">
     <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/><br>
     <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/><br>
     <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/><br>
     <button type="submit">Next</button>
 </form>​
```

Related: [Center a div in body](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/how-to-vertically-center-a-div-for-all-browsers/46367524#46367524)

Answer (score 1):

You can indeed center vertically and horizontally the single  container without a wrapper. The key is to understand what 100% height and width mean. It means the percentage of the parent element. You must chain percentages upward the hierarchy until you hit the actual viewport height and width.

HTML Element <---> BODY Element <----> DIV Element

100% of height in the DIV looks up the height of BODY, which in turn looks up the height of HTML, which in turn looks up the size of the viewport. In order for it to work properly, you cannot combine HTML and BODY in CSS, but rather address them separately.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

div {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div>
      Center me!
    </div>
  </body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

A [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/23NUC/4/) example with table warp

In the above solution, Provide css for html & body with `"height: 100%"` and then wrap the form that to be centered around a table.

Code sample

```
<html>
<body>    
<table height="100%" width="100%" border="1">
    <tr>
    <td>
    <form name="signup" class="signup" action="signup.php" style="border: 1px solid #000; ">

                <input type="text" placeholder="Email"/><br>

                <input type="text" placeholder="Username"/><br>

                <input type="password" placeholder="Password"/><br>

                <button type="submit">Next</button>

            </form>
        </td>
        </tr>
</table>    
</body>
</html>
```

​

Comment: this doesn't look centered thought... why you post a fiddle which doens't do what was asked?

Comment: sorry.. forgot to update the JSFiddle... have updated the http://jsfiddle.net/23NUC/4/

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

**Style.css**

```
div {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

I found this code snippet [here](http://zerosixthree.se/vertical-align-anything-with-just-3-lines-of-css/).

Answer (score 0):

With modern CSS you can simply wrap the content needing to be centered vertically within an element by making the container grid and giving it a height.

IF you need it both vertical and horizontal you can give the content a width or just let the content decide and then use `place-items:center;` on the grid.  This is a shortcut for `align-items:center; justify-items:center;`

Note also I set the flex direction to column and removed the now not-needed `<br >` IF you want some space between them just add a gap with some sort of a size to the container (form in this case) `gap: 1em;` OR just a space vertically `row-gap: 1em;` will do that.

Grid reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_grid_layout

Placement Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/place-items

Gap Reference" https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gap

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.signup {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<form name="signup" class="signup" action="signup.php">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
  <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
  <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
  <button type="submit">Next</button>
</form>
```

Fully "super-centered" example with gaps added:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.content-container {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #00FF0040;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.signup {
  background-color: #FF00FF20;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.signup * {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  height: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="content-container">
  <form name="signup" class="signup" action="signup.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Sticky header and footer with "super-centered" content "main" container:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  height: 100vh;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 4em auto 2em;
  gap: 0.25em;
  grid-template-areas: 'header' 'main' 'footer';
}

.header-container, .footer-container {
  justify-items: center;
  background-color: #00DDD040;
  display: grid;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
    border:#00DDD0 solid;
    border-width:0;
}

.header-container {
  grid: header;
   border-bottom-width: 0.25em;
}

.footer-container {
  grid: footer;
  border-top-width: 0.25em;
}

.content-container {
  grid: main;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #00FF00;
  padding: 1em;
  background-color: #00FF0040;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  width: 75vw;
}

.signup {
  background-color: #FF00FF20;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: 1em;
  border-radius: 0.5em;
}

.signup * {
  border-radius: 0.5em;
  height: 2em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-container">My header</header>
<div class="content-container">
  <form name="signup" class="signup" action="signup.php">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Email" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Username" />
    <input type="password" placeholder="Password" />
    <button type="submit">Next</button>
  </form>
</div>
<footer class="footer-container">My footer container</footer>
```

Answer (score -5):

css:
width : 200px;
margin 0 auto;

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).