# Container stuck to top of page

Tags: html, css

I want to vertically center a container div on the page. This works on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/erhzfryv/), but when I preview the page on my computer the container stays stuck to the top of the page. The body also seems to only fill half the page.

[image]

Does anyone know the reason for this? I don't know if it's the code, seeing as it works on JSfiddle.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
                    <div class="panel login-tab">
                        <div class="panel-heading">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="#" class="active" id="login-link">Login</a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-xs-6">
                                    <a href="#" id="register-link">Register</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                    <form id="login-form" method="post" style="display:block;">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="checkbox" tabindex="3" class="" name="remember" id="remember">
                                            <label for="remember">Remember me</label>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                    <input type="submit" name="login-submit" id="login-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-login" value="Log In">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-lg-12">
                                                    <div class="text-center">
                                                        <a href="#" tabindex="5" class="forgot-password">
                                                        Forgot password?</a>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                    <form id="register-form" method="post" style="display:none;">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="text" name="username" id="username" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" value="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="email" name="email" id="email" tabindex="1" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" value="">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" name="password" id="password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <input type="password" name="confirm-password" id="confirm-password" tabindex="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Conform Password">
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <div class="row">
                                                <div class="col-sm-6 col-sm-offset-3">
                                                    <input type="submit" name="register-submit" id="register-submit" tabindex="4" class="form-control btn btn-register" value="Register">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Other stylesheets:

```
<!--in head-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

<!--before ending body-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: To tell you more, we need to see the rest of your stylesheets. I think there are some rules which overwrites the html,body { height: 100% ... } properties.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12771982/vertically-centering-a-div-in-body. The issue fundamentally is that the `body` in jsfiddle fills up the page, but your alignment is being done inside a container that is not as large as the page.

Comment: @Fantasterei edited to include stylesheets

Comment: @ChrisLear When I check the body's height it doesn't fill up the entire page. At least not on my computer.

Comment: @l-emi I ran your code, just adding `body` tags, and it worked fine. so ignore my last comment - sorry. There must be something else messing with the styling.

Comment: Ah, figured the problem out! It has a very simple answer which I feel bad for not noticing: I was linking to the wrong stylesheet. Thanks for all the help anyway guys! :)