# Vertically center a div with variable height within a div that is 100% of the viewport

Tags: css, height, vertical-alignment

I know it looks like a question that has been asked many times, but I just couldn't find the solution to that very specific situation.

Here's the basic wireframe of my layout :

[image]

Basically, I've got a few divs with different backgrounds that take 100% width and 100% height of the browser window. Within each and every of them is another div that takes 50% width of its parent but has a variable height, depending on its content.

I'd like all of these divs-within-a-div to be vertically align. 
Now, I've read that putting a display:table-cell and a vertical-align:middle on the parent should work, but in this case it just seems to mess things up. :-/

My code:

```
<head>
<style>
     html, body {
            height: 100%;
        }
        body > div {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            background-size: cover;
        }

        .centered {
            width: 50%;
            margin: 0 auto;
            background: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
            padding: 50px 0 30px 0;
        }
</style>
</head>
        <body>

            <div id="pic_1">
                    <div class="centered">content</div>
            </div>

            <div id="pic_2">
                    <div class="centered">content</div>
            </div>

            <div id="pic_3">
                    <div class="centered">content</div> 
            </div>  

        </body>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center content with variable height within a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div)

Answer (score 2):

Set a grandparent element to be `display:table; height:100%` and the parent element to be `display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle`.

See "Method 1" [here](http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/) for an example.

<sub>*Also, note that your markup [should not use `class="centered"`](http://phrogz.net/css/HowToDevelopWithCSS.html#semanticselector); use a semantic class name instead.*</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It does work really well when there's only one parent. In this case, though, the divs #pic_1, #pic_2 and #pic_3 seem to assemble in a 3-column layout, each taking 33% of the width of the browser. I tried setting their width to 100%, but it didn't work: they were still in a 3-column layout. Only this time, #pic_1 seemed to take 66% width and the other two shared what was left. :-/

Comment: If you want three of them vertically stacked then you need three tables (three grandparent elements) each with `height:100%`.