# centering a div vertically inside another div with 100% height

Tags: css, responsive-design, vertical-alignment

I want to center a div inside a div that has 100% height. basically the main div comes before the site. i upload a image so you can understand better what i want to do.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's The Best Way of Centering a Div Vertically with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/396145/whats-the-best-way-of-centering-a-div-vertically-with-css)

Comment: Also take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113676/vertically-center-a-div-with-variable-height-within-a-div-that-is-100-of-the-vi?rq=1

Comment: Unfortunately, this requires you to set a fixed height on the container (why, browsers, why???).

Comment: If the centred div is fixed size, `position:absolute;top:50%;margin-top:-200px;` (for a 400px high div. you get the idea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using CSS [Flexbox](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-flexbox/#flex) is an option, you could simply achieve that by displaying the container as `flex` box and align the inner div at the middle (horizontally and vertically) as follows:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://codepen.io/hashem/pen/nKImz)**

```css
#intro {
    height: 100%; /* Or 100vh */

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;     /* Align the inner div vertically */
    justify-content: center; /* Align the inner div horizontally */
}
```

In this example, [`align-items`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#align-items-property) and [`justify-content`](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-flexbox/#propdef-justify-content) would make the inner div display at the middle of the `#intro`, vertically and horizontally.

By adding vendor prefixes, it should work on IE 10 as well. (I used Autoprefixer in the demo).

However in order to support old web browsers give this approach a try (take a look at **Vertical Alignment** section):

- [Vertically align an image inside a div with responsive height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18516317/vertically-align-an-image-inside-a-div-with-responsive-height/18516474#18516474)

Comment: Right, Do I have an alternative? That works on IE 9 ?