# Reveal text on image hover (vertically centered)

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

Trying to figure out how I can vertically center the text that shows up when the images are hovered in this demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/XCNKj/

HTML

```
<div class="main">       
  <article class="work" id="project-1">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/sports-q-g-430-269-5.jpg">
    <div class="covering background"></div>
    <div class="covering foreground">
        <h2>Project 1</h2>
    </div>
  </article>  
  <article class="work" id="project-2">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/nightlife-q-g-430-269-2.jpg">
    <div class="covering background"></div>
    <div class="covering foreground">
        <h2>Project 2</h2>
    </div>
  </article>   
</div>
```

CSS

```
.work {
    width: 430px;
    height: 269px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;

    display: inline-table;
    position: relative;
}

.covering {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; left: 0;
    opacity: 0;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0);
}

.work:hover .covering {
    opacity: 1;
    filter:alpha(opacity=100);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.background {
    width: 100%; height: 100%;
    background: white;
}

.foreground {
    bottom: 0; right: 0;
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.work h2 {
    font: 36px/40px Helvetica;
    height:100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

The problem is that the images can vary in size and the caption that pop ups could be multiple lines.

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center content with variable height within a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

On non TD elements vertical center needs line-height to be set to a fix value. Replace the height attribute of your **`.work h2`** css by **`line-height: 269px;`**

```
.work h2 {
    font: 36px/40px Helvetica;
    line-height: 269px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that cause problems with multi line h2's?

Comment: Yes it's true, if you want to have a multi line h2 you should wrap it inside a table, see http://jsfiddle.net/XCNKj/26/

Comment: Thanks I appreicate your effort! But it's still problematic as the image size could vary, i e, they have dynamic size. Your fiddle is built upon fixed sizing.