# Vertically Center dynamic UL

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been trying to center an unordered list with dynamic height, without any success, so far.

Can it be done? And how?

I am looking for a solution that will be older browser friendly.

---

**The HTML:**

```
<div class="info gradient">

<ul>
<li><p class="text-01">Lorem</p> <p class="description-01">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>

<li><p class="text-02">Ipsum</p> <p class="description-02">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>

<li><p class="text-03">Dolor</p> <p class="description-03">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

---

**For the CSS take a look at the this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pbLBL/)**




Thanks.

Comment: vertically center within the browser window?  within the containing div?  or what?

Comment: Within the containing `<div class="info gradient">`.

Comment: can you list _which_ older browsers you care about?

Comment: @andi Mozila. IE. Safari.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center content with variable height within a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbLBL/12/)

HTML:

```
<div class="info gradient">
<div class="ul_wrap">
<ul>
<li><p class="text-01">Lorem</p> <p class="description-01">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>

<li><p class="text-02">Ipsum</p> <p class="description-02">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>

<li><p class="text-03">Dolor</p> <p class="description-03">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>
</ul>
    </div>

</div>
```

As said [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) The values `table` and `table-cell` for the `display` property are not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Answer (score 0):

You means like [**THIS FIDDLE?**](http://jsfiddle.net/pbLBL/8/)

CSS:

```
html, body, ul{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
body{
    position:fixed;
    text-align:center;
}
ul{
    display:table;
    list-style:none;
}
ul li{
    display:table-row;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No. As in, the dynamic `<ul>` centred vertically.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add `style="margin-left:200px"` at the beggining of each paragraph.

**Note:** You can adjust the px to however you want has long as each paragraph is the same

```
<div class="info gradient">

<ul>
<li><p class="text-01" style="margin-left:200px">Lorem</p> <p class="description-01" style="margin-left:200px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
</li>

<li><p class="text-02" style="margin-left:200px">Ipsum</p> <p class="description-02" style="margin-left:200px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>

<li><p class="text-03" style="margin-left:200px">Dolor</p> <p class="description-03" style="margin-left:250px">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</li>
</ul>

</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nate32100/j3aS2/

Comment: How exactly will this center the dynamic `<ul>` inside the containing `<div>`?

Comment: yes it does it makes them evenly (dynamically) aligned going down.

Comment: Could you please show me what you mean, in the FIDDLE linked above?

Comment: how do i make a fiddle

Comment: "how do i make a fiddle" => google it (use "jsfiddle" instead of "fiddle")