# Vertical-align middle with display table-cell not working on images

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, css-tables

I'm trying to use the vertical-align: middle on a layout to vertically center sometimes text, sometimes images, but it's only working on text. Can anyone tell me why?

HTML:

```
<div>
    <img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png"/>
</div>

<div>
    <span> text </span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div{
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:table;

    margin:10px;
}
img, span{
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9uD8M/ I created a fiddle aswell

Comment: Why do you need `display:table-cell`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Put `border: 1px solid black` on your `img, span` tags, then inspect both elements in the browser dev. console. You'll notice that the span defaults to 100% height of its parent, while the image has a defined height (the height of the actual image).

So you're not really vertically aligning those elements relative to the div, you're just vertically aligning the text inside the span element relative to the span :)

If you really want to use tables for vertical-centering, here's the correct code:
http://jsfiddle.net/WXLsY/

(`vertical-align` and `display:table-cell` go on the parent, and you need wrapper table on them)

But there are other ways to do this (SO has many answers to this question, just use search)

Comment: In your example, the `vertical-align: middle` property is not needed for the `img` and `span` child elements.  The rest of the CSS is sufficient, and the explanation is good.

Comment: I see, well tables are not needed per se, but I was using them succesfully with the text. My image is responsive so I don't know the width or height to be able to center via position:absolute for example

Comment: @Elaine: try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13075912/1058140). I have it in my favorites and use it every time I want to vertically align an element with variable height

Comment: @onetrickpony : How I can vertically center the div itself instead of it's contents *(when it's height is set by it's contents and not manually)*?

Comment: @user2284570 see http://css-tricks.com/centering-in-the-unknown or the link to the answer I posted above

Answer (score 4):

Here is one way of fixing the problem:

HTML:

```
<div>
    <span><img src="http://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" /></span>
</div>
<div> 
    <span> text </span>
</div>
```

Put your `img` in a `span`, the image is a replaced element, it cannot contain children content, hence, vertical-align will not work.

CSS:

```
div {
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    background-color:red;
    display:table;
    margin:10px;
}
span {
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```

See demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/Fz6Nj/

There are several ways of doing this, you could also apply `display: table-cell` to the parent `div` element, but that would be a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

In order to vertically align an image inside a table cell you need to give the image a display of block.

```
display: block
margin: 0 auto
```

the margin: 0 auto is to align the image to the center. If you want the image left aligned then don't include this. If you want the image right aligned you can add:

```
float: right
```

Thanks,
G

Answer (score -3):

You can try by adding -> line-height: 200px; in the span style section, I think it might work;