# Create Responsive button with vertical-align center

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm building a responsive site using bootstrap, trying to create some buttons.
I can't find a way to vertical align the text in the middle.
This is my code:

```
<div class="play col-xs-24 visible-xs-block">
   <div class="row movie_button">
      <div class="play_button inline_blocks col-xs-4">
         <img class="button_images movie_img_button" src="../images/btn.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-20 button_link ">
         <div id="play_title">PLAY THE MOVIE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried using `display: table-cell` but it didn't worked.

[image: This is what i want:]

Comment: Can you put your code in JSFiddle?

Answer (score 1):

### Possible solutions to vertical-align center:

**Solution - 1** - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u10mo6tL/)**

Set the line's height to the same height as the containing box element.

```
<div class="col-xs-20 button_link" style="height: 50px;">
    <div id="play_title" style="line-height: 50px; text-align:center;">PLAY THE MOVIE</div>
</div>
```

---

**Solution - 2** - **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/u10mo6tL/2/)**

Simulate table display behavior, since tables support vertical alignment: (Note: You don't need to set the `height` in your case, It's only for Demo)

```
<div class="col-xs-20 button_link" style="height: 50px; display: table;">
    <div id="play_title" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; text-align:center;">PLAY THE MOVIE</div>
</div>
```

**[EDITED]**

**TRY - 1** (For Solution - 2)

```
<div class="play col-xs-24 visible-xs-block">
   <div class="row movie_button">
      <div class="play_button inline_blocks col-xs-4">
         <img class="button_images movie_img_button" src="../images/btn.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-20 button_link" style="display: table;">
         <div id="play_title" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">PLAY THE MOVIE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**OR TRY - 2**

```
<div class="play col-xs-24 visible-xs-block">
   <div class="row movie_button" style="display: table;">
      <div class="play_button inline_blocks col-xs-4">
         <img class="button_images movie_img_button" src="../images/btn.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-20 button_link" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">
         <div id="play_title">PLAY THE MOVIE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**OR TRY - 3**

```
<div class="play col-xs-24 visible-xs-block">
   <div class="row movie_button" style="display: table;">
      <div class="play_button inline_blocks col-xs-4">
         <img class="button_images movie_img_button" src="../images/btn.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-20 button_link">
         <div id="play_title" style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;">PLAY THE MOVIE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Look at other Questions about Vertical-align middle with display table-cell not working???

**Question 1.** [Div table-cell vertical align not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005309/div-table-cell-vertical-align-not-working)

**Question 2.** [Vertical-align middle with display table-cell not working on images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20584777/vertical-align-middle-with-display-table-cell-not-working-on-images)

---

**Solution - 3**

Use `span` instead of `div` for `div#play_title` and add CSS Style `display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;` and `display:inline-block;` to the containing box element.

```
<div class="play col-xs-24 visible-xs-block">
   <div class="row movie_button">
      <div class="play_button inline_blocks col-xs-4">
         <img class="button_images movie_img_button" src="../images/btn.png">
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-20 button_link" style="display:inline-block;">
         <span id="play_title" style="display:inline-block; vertical-align:middle;">PLAY THE MOVIE</span>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks but solution 1 i don't know the height because it's responsive and solution 2 not working.

Comment: @user2587454 could you provide me a working DEMO or [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: @user2587454 TRY - [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/) for creating a Bootstrap demo and you can also use [placehold.it](http://placehold.it/) for an image placeholder.

Comment: @user2587454 -- choose this answer if it has been helpful to you.