# vertically centering the element for auto height div

Tags: css

html:

```
<div id="main">
    <div id="foo">foo</div>
</div>
```

css:

```
html,body{
    height: 100%;
}
#main{
    height: 100%;
}
#foo{
    height: auto;
    /* height: 100%; I cannot use height 100% or fixed height for this element*/
}
#foo:before{
    content: "bar";
/*I want to use the height in percentage which won't work but work with px*/
    height: 100%;
    display: block;/* or inline-block*/
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w1rfz103/)

I cannot use flexbox css for some reason. And I also tried with transform css technique and various techniques such as table but even couldn't get vertical center.

I cannot change the markup and please if possible without touching the css for #main would be great for me.

Comment: Are you after something like [this example](http://jsbin.com/pulora/1/edit?html,css,output) ?

Comment: Hmmm, something like that (centering just foo). Amazed, not working with my site...

Comment: "bar" is going to come along for the ride because it is a child of `#foo`. Its the same as this: `<div id="foo"><div>bar</div>foo</div>`. To break it out, you would have to [do something like this example](http://jsbin.com/pulora/2/edit)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center content with variable height within a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div)

Answer (score 1):

You can center an element vertically within it's container using this technique:

```
#foo{
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; // move down 50% of parent
    transform: translateY(-50%); // move back up 50% of own height
}
```

Set `position: relative;` on the `#main` container to make `#foo` relate to it.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w1rfz103/3/)

Comment: centering just foo not bar, though I've already tried this technique but not working with my site....

Comment: You want bar to be at the top while foo is vertically aligned?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#foo {
height: auto;
margin:auto;
position:absolute;
top:50%;
}
```

Comment: the updated answer should place the #foo in the middle of the screen, the problem would be is that if #foo is 300px, it will be 50% from the top of the screen but wouldn't be right in the middle, unless you have
#foo {top: calc(50% - 150px);} /* half the height of #foo */