# How to keep the div at the center of the screen always with fixed width and 100% height?

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am new to CSS. I want to keep the `div` always at the center of the screen. I know by positioning we can achieve it but that is only when we have fixed width and height. What my requirement is, I want to have a `div` with fixed width but no fixed height. I want it to get adjusted to the center based on the content inside it using `CSS`.

Comment: Hi would appreciate it if you could give us a jsFiddle to play around with.

Comment: And yes, it _is_ a repeated question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for `transform: translateY(-50%)` property. Here is an example:

```
.main {
    width: 200px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin: auto;
}
```

**[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/91LhdbqL/)**

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like this and you can be sure that it will always be in the middle.

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer">
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
* {
    margin: 0 auto; /* centers everything except if otherwise floated 
   or affected by positioning positioning and margin property values */
}


#outer {
    width: 200px;
    height: auto;

}


#content {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: green;
    bottom: 0;

}
```

[See working example here](http://jsfiddle.net/1ade8mg5/1/)

**Solution:** Wrapped the DIV in question in a none floated div that listen to the first block of CSS code and I didn't do anything that will affect its position.