# How to vertically center a image in a div?

Tags: html, css

I have the following image in a div

```
  <div id="left-control">
      <img src="img/icons/ic_next_3x_re.png" />
   </div>
```

Here is the css

```
#left-control {
   height: 100%;
   float: left;
}

#left-control > img {
    display: block;
    margin: 250px 0;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

But for some reason I can't seem to vertically center the image no matter what CSS I try. Any suggestions?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to vertically center content with variable height within a div?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div)

Comment: flexbox is covered in the url in the first post

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/by93hgyq/

Comment: Also, setting the background-color on your div to red will reveal why you're not seeing vertical centering.

Answer (score 3):

There isn't an amazing way to accomplish this, but what is below should do the trick.

```
#left-control {
   float: left;
   height: 100%;
}

#left-control:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

#left-control img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Here is a [simple fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g794em4b/). Keep in mind that I manually set the height for the `#left-control` element in this example since fiddle wasn't allowing for 100%.

Comment: hey is there a way to horizontally center as well with this? `margin: 0 auto;` does not seem to work. [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/g794em4b/1/)

Comment: @Solace Remove the float: left; and add text-align: center;

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS tables to accomplish this.

```css
.wrapper {
   display: table;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#left-control {
  height: 100%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#left-control > .img {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="left-control">
    <div class="img"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could wrap the img, inside another div like so..

```
<div id="left-control">
      <div class="vert-align">
         <img src="img/icons/ic_next_3x_re.png" />
      </div>
   </div>
```

then, in the css do something like this...

```
#left-control {
   height: 100%;
   position:relative;
}

#left-control > img {
    display: block;
    margin: 250px 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

.vert-align{
    position: absolute:
    margin: auto:
    top:0; left:0; right:0; bottom:0;
    height: 100px;
}
```

you can play with top left right and bottom properties to set it to the desired position.