# Horizontally centering image inside <a>, why is margin:0 auto; NOT working?

Tags: html, css, center, margin

[**JSFiddle here.**](https://jsfiddle.net/KheKhe/g794em4b/2/)

OR

```css
#left-control {
   float: left;
   height: 300px;
   width:300px;
   background-color:crimson;
}

#left-control:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

#left-control img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a id="left-control">
    <img src="https://events.columbia.edu/3.10/calrsrc.MainCampus/themes/columbiaTheme/resourcesColumbia/FacebookIcon.png" />
 </a>
```

I have taken the following hack from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31844276/how-to-vertically-center-a-image-in-a-div) to vertically center an `img` in an `a` tag.

The problem is that I am used to using `margin:0 auto;` to center things. But the problem is that it is not working along with this technique of centering vertically.

Why is that? What can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image width is not 100%, thus a `margin: 0 auto;` will not work to center align the image. Your best bet is to do a `text-align: center;` on the `<a>` tag with ID `left-control` to make the icon center-aligned.

Answer (score 2):

Use following css:

```
#left-control::before {
    height: 100%;
    content: "";
}
#left-control {
    background-color: crimson;
    display: table;
    height: 300px;
    line-height: 300px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Remove  `float: left;` from `#left-control`. And use `display: table;` `line-height: 300px;`  `text-align: center;`

And remove `display: inline-block;` `vertical-align: middle;` from `#left-control::before`

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g794em4b/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

Add text align `#left-control` `text-align:center`

```css
#left-control {
   float: left;
   height: 300px;
   width:300px;
text-align:center;
   background-color:crimson;
}

#left-control:before {
    content: "";
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    height: 100%;
}

#left-control img {
    vertical-align: middle;
    z-index: 1;
 
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<a id="left-control">
    <img src="https://events.columbia.edu/3.10/calrsrc.MainCampus/themes/columbiaTheme/resourcesColumbia/FacebookIcon.png" />
 </a>
```