# Newsletter align in centre issue

Tags: php, html, css

I have a newsletter that I want to position in the center (HORIZONTALLY) and for it to remain in the center for all devices (assuming I don't want to use media tags). I'm not going to upload the PHP I've used for the newsletter form since it isn't relative. Can anyone see from the code and image attached [image]alone what I need to do to get both the title and the newsletter form to always be in the middle? Thanks

```
HERE ARE THE HTML DIVS AND H1 CLASSES
    <div class="ty-footer-form-block">
        <h1 class=".ty-footer-form-block__title">NEWSLETTER</h1>
        <div class="ty-footer-form-block__form ty-control-group ty-input-append">
        <div>
    </div>

HERE IS THE CSS
    .ty-footer-form-block {
        height: 180px;
        background: #fafafa;
        border-top: 5px solid #fff;
        border-bottom: 5px solid #fff;
        color: white;
    }

    .ty-footer-form-block__form {
        margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
        width: 550px;
        top: 80px;
        left: 50%;
        color: #c9c9c9;
    }

    .ty-footer-form-block__title {
        color: #000;
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 500;
        text-align: centre;
        position: relative;
        top:35px;
        left:50%;
    }

    .ty-input-append {
        position: relative;
        margin: 10px 0 0 0;
        width: 100%;
        padding-right: 35px;
    }

    .ty-control-group {
        display: none;
        margin: 0 0 12px 0;
        width: 100%;
        vertical-align: middle;
        .clearfix();
    }
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div/27663253#27663253 Shameless plug

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try changing `text-align: centre` to `text-align: center`

Comment: Thanks. Can't believe I missed that hahahaha

Comment: css is an american made language so it will use american spelling

Comment: That's so annoying. Thanks :D