# How to horizontally and vertically center an object within a container that has no set height?

Tags: css, html

If you needed to horizontally and vertically center an object within a container that has no set height, how would you accomplish that?

Comment: https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/center.en.html

Comment: display grid, flex, table-cell, ... ?  have you tried anything yet ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to vertically center content with variable height within a div?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div)

Answer (score 0):

```css
.centerDiv {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="centerDiv">hello</div>
```