# Center child to the center of its parent

Tags: html, css

Within my `<ul>` I ofcourse have a few `<li>`. These list-items need to be centered vertically and the background has to be full width and height.

The way I tried was by using `align-items: center;` on the `<ul>` and I tried `align-self: center;` on the `<li>`

Here is my code as it is right now:

```css
.desktop-menu-left {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.desktop-menu-left li {
    height: 100%;
}

.desktop-menu-left li a {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="desktop-menu-left">
  <li class="darkblue"><a href="#">Opleidingen</a></li>
  <li class="orange"><a href="#">Leren bij *</a></li>
  <li class="green"><a href="#">Open huis</a></li>
  <li class="pink"><a href="#">Voor bedrijven</a></li>
  <li class="darkorange"><a href="#">Over *</a></li>
  <li class="lightblue"><a href="#">Niews</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: to center where? there is not height, you occupy all the height with your ul

Comment: @TemaniAfif so I have to give my li a height of 100% and then center the li?

Comment: 100% of what? you need to be clear on how to center? relatively to what ?

Comment: @TemaniAfif , so I have to give my ul a static height?

Comment: @TemaniAfif now it gets centered right, but the background-color takes the width of the text and not the full-width/height

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this is case, it's better to use **flexbox**, because with grid, if you want to add a `<li>` in HTML, you have to change CSS, too.

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}

.desktop-menu-left {
  height: 100%;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.desktop-menu-left>li {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.desktop-menu-left>li:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #555;
}

.desktop-menu-left a {
  display: block;
  padding: 0 0.5rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="desktop-menu-left">
  <li><a href="#">Opleidingen</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Leren bij *</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Open huis</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Voor bedrijven</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Over *</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Niews</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

I played a little with your code.
Is that the kind of result you want to achieve?

```css
/* Added here */
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
}

/* Added colors */
.darkblue {
  background-color: darkblue;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.pink {
  background-color: pink;
}

.darkorange {
  background-color: darkorange;
}

.lightblue {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.desktop-menu-left {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto auto auto auto;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.desktop-menu-left li {
  height: 100%;
  list-style-type: none; /* Added */
}

.desktop-menu-left li a {
  padding: 0 10px;
  /* Added */
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <ul class="desktop-menu-left">
    <li class="darkblue"><a href="#">Opleidingen</a></li>
    <li class="orange"><a href="#">Leren bij *</a></li>
    <li class="green"><a href="#">Open huis</a></li>
    <li class="pink"><a href="#">Voor bedrijven</a></li>
    <li class="darkorange"><a href="#">Over *</a></li>
    <li class="lightblue"><a href="#">Niews</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

I often use this center method as a class to reuse it easily, like this:
`.center-y { top: 50%; transform: translateY(-50%); }`

Hope it helps.

Comment: This is indeed what I need! Nice way to do indeed. I only figured it out as well. I just had to add display:grid and align-items:center to the li

Comment: I can't give any votes yet. My reputation is to low, but I would give you ;)

Comment: @Lenap Nice. :) I often use this center method as a class like this: `.center-y { position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%); }` (Thanks in advance!)

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed it by setting `display: grid; and align-items: center;` on the `li` so I didn't had to set a height to any element.

Answer (score -3):

You should give your `desktop-menu-left` a `height` and `width` to have a full width and height background, for instance with `height: 100%;`.

Then you can also align your list items vertically according to [the answer of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59309/how-to-vertically-center-content-with-variable-height-within-a-div).